# Angular Apply already in progress

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using an angular js plugin called intro.js. It can be found [here](http://introjs.com/). What I want to do with this is open up a dropdown when the user clicks on the demo button so that I can show some intro steps for the dropdown items. Here's my html:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as ctrl">
    <div ng-intro-options="ctrl.IntroOptions"
         ng-intro-method="ctrl.CallMe">
            <div class="container">
                <button class="btn btn-success" 
                ng-click="ctrl.startHelp()">Help</button>
            </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And my JS:

```
MainCtrl.prototype.startHelp = function() {
    var _this = this;
    angular.element('#drop-down-button').trigger('click');
    _this.CallMe();
};
```

I've also tried

```
angular.element('#drop-down-button').click();
```

But the same error. The intro works just fine if i remove the `angular.element` line. However, with that included I get [this error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog?p0=$apply). Any idea how to get around this?

Comment: can you try wrap your click code with a setTimeout like this `setTimeout(function(){angular.element('#drop-down-button').trigger('click'); }, 200);`

Comment: @Akis_Tfs haha you and I came to the same solution at the same time

Comment: haha lol yes it was the same exact time!

Comment: This is what 'don't use jQuery with Angular' statement is about. Drop-down action should be triggered in normal way, not by emulating user actions with 'click'.

Comment: @Richard what @estus said is absolutely correct, you should toggle your drop down with a more proper way like `$("#drop-down-button").dropdown('toggle')`, depends on what drop down you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had to wrap the call inside of a timeout.

```
MainCtrl.prototype.startHelp = function() {
    var _this = this;
    _this.$timeout(function() {
        angular.element('#drop-down-button').trigger('click');
    }, 0, false);
    _this.CallMe();
};
```